# Как узнать директорию исполняемого файла в Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Консольная программа на C++ должна сама себя при запуске прописывать в автозагрузку Windows (через реестр). Важная деталь заключается в том, что мы не знаем места расположения этой программы на диске. Собственно, как это можно сделать?

Comment: В регистре это идет в `HKLM\Windows/CurrentVersion\Run`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы в Windows достать директорию из которой запущена программа используйте вызов `_getcwd` из `direct.h` примерно так:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <direct.h>

char current_work_dir[FILENAME_MAX];
_getcwd(current_work_dir, sizeof(current_work_dir));
```

Также можно попробовать WinAPI вызов [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx)
или посмотреть значение `argv[0]`

Comment: +1, но `argv[0]` [может содержать любую ерунду](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2051031/276994), которую туда положит запускающий процесс.

Comment: getcwd не обязан совпадать с каталогом, где находиться приложение. Да, оно иногда совпадает (если с проводника двойным кликом запускать).

Answer (score 3):

так

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LPTSTR ExtractFilePath(LPCTSTR FileName, LPTSTR buf)
{  
    int i, len = lstrlen(FileName);
    for(i=len-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(FileName[i] == _T('\\'))
            break;
    }
    lstrcpyn(buf, FileName, i+2);
    return buf;
}

// szFileName - содержит путь к exe-файлу
// szPath - содержит путь к папке, в которой находится exe-файл
TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH], szPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(0, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
ExtractFilePath(szFileName, szPath);
```

Comment: @Abyx не гарантирует, только если путь не помещается в буфер, но я так и не нашел способа запустить приложение с путем длиннее, чем MAX_PATH.

Comment: @Abyx я пытался создать процесс с таким путем помощью CreateProcess, не заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не изменяет память метод main выглядит примерно так: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` где argv[0] это путь к нашему *.exe файлу

Comment: Мне кажется, это единственный заслуживающий внимания ответ. Нулевой аргумент `main` функции всегда будет содержать путь к файлу программы безо всяких WinAPI и прочих библиотек.

Comment: До тех пор пока тот парень из Индии ВНЕЗАПНО не решит изменить сигнатуру точки входа на void my_main_without_argv()

Comment: Не совсем так. Смотрите комментарий к принятому ответу.

Comment: @VladD Да, действительно стандарт этого не гарантирует. Я этого не знал. Однако, то, что вы имеете ввиду, похоже, относится к запуску процесса через `exec` под никсами и вряд ли может относиться к Windows.

Comment: @VisioN: Это касается и Windows. Процесс запускается через `CreateProcess` (остальные методы по существу пользуются `CreateProcess` внутри себя), и вы можете передать любую ком. строку (см. case 3 [здесь](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175986)).

Comment: Вы получите путь к exe-файлу, а не путь к каталогу, из которого была запущена программа (CWD).