# Путь к файлу программы без консоли. С++

Tags: c++, windows, консоль

Всем привет, мне нужно узнать программно где лежат файл программы.

Это делается так если включена консоль.

```
#include<string>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    //Получить текущую деректорию
    //TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
    //GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(buffer),buffer);
    //cout << buffer << endl;


    if(argc > 0)
    {
    //получаим путь к програме
    string urlK = ""; 
    urlK += argv[0];
    //удаляем всё до слеша (название програмы)
    while(urlK.size() > 0) { bool br = 0;if(urlK[urlK.size()-1] == '/' || urlK[urlK.size()-1] == '\\'){br = 1;}
    urlK.erase(urlK.size()-1); if(br)break; }
    //устанавливаем путь к каталогу с программой как основной
    SetCurrentDirectory(urlK.c_str());
    }
return;
}
```

Вот элемент массива что содержат путь к нужному файлу.
argv[0]

Проблема появляться если в проекте отключить консоль, тогда путь определяет совсем не тот что нужно.

**Подскажите как получить путь к файлу если консоль отключена.**

**Без внешних библиотек по возможности (не верю что стандартных нет)**

**C++ vs 2010**

Также хотелось бы узнать как называется система когда на окно перетаскивают файлы и программа определит их пути, (хочу задать по теме вопрос но без названия не получиться)

**Вот жылаемый ответ. Спасибо Владимиу Мартьянову я набросал вот такой ответ на основе его. Из тех ответов что эсть ни один неприемлем для искателей из поисковика.**

```
#include<Windows.h> 
#include<fstream> 

char* SvcInstall() 
{ 
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];     if( !GetModuleFileName( NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH ) ) 
    { 
        return "error"; 
    } 
    return szPath; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    //Функцыя возвращает путь к файлу програмы
    //SvcInstall()

    std::ofstream of("text.txt"); 
    of<<SvcInstall()<<std::endl; 
    of.close();
    system("text.txt");
    system("pause");
    exit(0); 
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать директорию исполняемого файла в Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414690/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-windows)

Comment: "я набросал вот такой ответ" - у szPath явно не хватает "static". И даже с ним возвращать указатель на внутренний массив символов - плохая идея. Если пишите (по настоящему) на с++, возвращайте std::string.

Comment: "Также хотелось бы узнать как называется система когда на окно перетаскивают файлы и программа определит их пути" - Drag & Drop?

Comment: Drop если вы для роботы с окном используете glfw вот пример сокращонно

Comment: glfwSetDropCallback(window,drop); //регистрацыя
void drop(GLFWwindow* window,int count, const char** patch)
{
 std::ofstream e("1.txt");
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
  e<<i<<" -> "<<patch[i]<<std::endl;
 e.close();
 system("1.txt");
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это делается через `GetModuleFileName()`, в качестве хэндла нужно указать NULL.

Comment: А можно пример заполненной GetModuleFileName(); Оно же возвращает стандартный char* Без всяких неконвертируемых виндовс строк?

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка возвращает оно длину строки, записанной в буфер. Пример - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683500(v=vs.85).aspx

Что такое "неконвертируемых виндовс строк" я не совсем понимаю. Функция есть в ASCII и Unicode-вариантах.

Comment: У меня пример не работает пишет что SVCNAME,                   // name of service  не определен какой библиотеки не хватает.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка а вы попробуйте понять что там в примере написано и использовать только то, что надо.

Comment: добавте этот пример пожалуйста к ответу  #include<Windows.h>
#include<fstream>

char* SvcInstall()
{
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

    if( !GetModuleFileName( NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH ) )
    {
        return "error";
    }

    return szPath;
}

int main()
{
 std::ofstream of("text.txt");
 of<<SvcInstall()<<std::endl;
 exit(0);
}

Answer (score 1):

В новом стандарте (C++17) появилась такая возможность (На основе **boost/filesystem**) получение пути: `std::filesystem::current_path`. [**Вот ссылка**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path). Думаю, что уже можно  активно ее использовать. А вот на счет наличие новых стандартов в msvs 2010 не знаю. Лучше же переходить на более новые. Либо лайвхаки по использованию нового SDK для старых версий.

Comment: Спасибо но я не переношу новых визуалок с привязкой к акаунту, хоть и не против использовуть новый стандарт но в 2010 его нет. а сам  boost мне так и не удалось установить в визуалку хотя люди делают.

Comment: Следует переходить на новые стандарты. С++20 не за горами.

Comment: Если сделают адэкватное IDE или научатся встраевать в визуалку 2010 новый стандарт, с радост.ю перед. А можно вопрос? Новый стандарт вмещает в себе и старый набор и новый ведь?